# Display image from encoded base64 on pug (jade) using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

How to decode this data (I'm not sure if what type is this) and display the image. I'm using pug as template engine.

Here is the data that I need to display as an image:

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QBaRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABQ ...and so on

I tried this code in my node.js but it doesn't work

```
var img = Buffer.from(image).toString('base64');
```

The variable image is from this response:
[image: response]

While this code is for passing data to .pug file

```
res.render('getsurveyemployeeimg', {
   surveyId: results[0].surveyId,
   empNo: results[0].empNo,
   empName: employee.result.fullnameEn,
   empImg: img,
   date: created,
   answers: results
});
```

.pug file

```
img(src="data:image/jpg;base64,#{empImg}")
```

I always keep on getting broken image icon as an output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code is for passing data to .pug file:

```
res.render('getsurveyemployeeimg', {
   surveyId: results[0].surveyId,
   empNo: results[0].empNo,
   empName: employee.result.fullnameEn,
   empImg: image,
   date: created,
   answers: results
});
```

.pug file should look like this:

```
img(src="data:image/jpg;base64," + empImg)
```

After that, everything should work if `empImg` actually contains a `base64` image.

Comment: What is contained in the `image` variable?

Comment: it's a response from an external api

Comment: Is this a string? This string is exactly the correct picture?

Comment: it's the random numbers and letters returned from the api call, they said i should decode it to be displayed as an image

Comment: Then the problems are in the variable `image`. Can you show a more detailed code or provide documentation for this API?

Comment: i edited my post, i included a screenshot from postman

Comment: It seems like I understood. You do not need to make a `buffer`, you just need to pass `image` to `empImg`.

Comment: I'm very glad that my decision helped you. Regarding thanks in the comments - you need to read [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks you.